# Javascript on Python Django, hosted on pythonanywhere

Tags: javascript, django

I'm teaching myself Django, and decided to try out some JS functionality. I included a simple text-changing function (from w3schools) in a JS script to try things out. The app is `blog`, and the JS script lives in `blog/static/blog/test.js`. There's only one function in there:

```
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("demo-btn").innerHTML = "Text changed.";
}
```

Which is linked to a button in `blog/templates/blog/post_list.html`, `id="demo-btn"`.

Website live here: http://andreyito.pythonanywhere.com

It works fine on my localhost, but when I push it to `pythonanywhere`, nothing happens (clicking on the `Click me` button is supposed to change the text just above the button.)

This feels like a minor thing that I'm leaving out, but I haven't been able to easily troubleshoot this. Repo here:https://github.com/Don86/djgirls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `test.js` file is not loading in the pythonanywhere hosting:

[image]

You can see their documentation on how they work with static files. Also maybe you did not run `python manage.py collectstatic` which loads the file in the static directory. Please see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) for more details. Also you can check how they setup the static files in this [documentation](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/).

Comment: Following the instructions [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/), I (1) ran `python3 manage.py collectstatic`, (2) checked that the static file mapping was defined in the `pthonanywhere` web tab, in the "static file" section. Still no dice, unfortunately.

Just in case this helps: `grep "STATIC_ROOT" settings.py` returns `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

Comment: Solved: did a stupid where I had `/static` in `.gitignore` during initial upload.

Comment: Hahahaha. No worries :)